# summarizing data based on a pre-set condition and adding a (0,1) flag

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have the following data frame `df` with the following columns:

```
df <-   
REP  METRIC  BE 
1     A      1
2     A      0
3     A      1
1     B      1
2     B      1 
3     B      1
1     C      0
2     C      1
3     C      1
```

I want to summarize the data by REP such that for each unique `REP` if `BE` is `1` for both `Metric` `A` and `B` then add a new column `BEBOTH` with `1` otherwise it is `0` (i.e. if any of them is zero, then `BEBOTH` is zero).

The output should be:

```
 REP  BEBOTH
  1     1
  2     0
  3     1
```

How may I do this in R?  I triled to use `ifelse` statement but I didn't get that right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(rep = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
             metric  = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
             be      = c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0))

res <- df %>% 
group_by(rep) %>%
mutate(beboth = ifelse(grep("A|B", metric) && be==0, 0, 1))

res
#Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
#Groups: rep [3]
#
#    rep metric    be beboth
#  (dbl)  (chr) (dbl)  (dbl)
#1     1      A     1      1
#2     2      A     0      0
#3     3      A     1      1
#4     1      B     1      1
#5     2      B     1      0
#6     3      B     1      1
#7     1      C     1      1
#8     2      C     1      0
#9     3      C     0      1
```

If all you care about is the rep and beboth you can summarize it:

```
res.summarized <- df %>% 
  group_by(rep) %>%
  mutate(beboth = ifelse(grep("A|B", metric) && be==0, 0, 1)) %>%
  summarize(first(beboth))

res.summarized
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#    rep first(beboth)
#  (dbl)         (dbl)
#1     1             1
#2     2             0
#3     3             1
```

**Edit**: I updated my answer to have it look at only A and B

Comment: Actually, I have also Metric `C` that has `BE` value of 0 or 1. Is there a way to specify Metric name in the ifelse statement instead of `any(be==0)`?

Comment: @Amer so you only want it to summarize A and B in beboth?

Comment: Yes. BEBOTH should be conditioned only on the `BE` value of Metric A and B only. The code won't be correct incase I have Metric C that has a BE value of 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`. Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'REP', we get the logical condition and wrap it with `+` to coerce to numeric.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(BEBOTH= +(any((METRIC=="A" & BE==1)) & any(METRIC=="B" & BE==1))) , by = REP]
#   REP BEBOTH
#1:   1      1
#2:   2      0
#3:   3      1
```

---

Or using the same logic with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(REP) %>% 
  summarise(BEBOTH = +(any(METRIC=="A" & BE==1) & any(METRIC=="B" & BE==1)))
#    REP BEBOTH
#   (int)  (int)
#1     1      1
#2     2      0
#3     3      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer using base packages:

```
evaluate_BEBOTH <- function(x){
    subset_df <- df[x,]

    if (sum(subset_df[,'BE']) == 2)
        return (1)
    else
        return (0)
}

df$BEBOTH <- ave(1:nrow(df),df$REP,FUN = evaluate_BEBOTH)

df
  REP METRIC BE BEBOTH
1   1      A  1      1
2   2      A  0      0
3   3      A  1      1
4   1      B  1      1
5   2      B  1      0
6   3      B  1      1
```